# Access WordPress Tag Function From Modal

Tags: plugin-development, taxonomy, tags

I am currently working on a plugin that will require the use of the Tag library inside the given WordPress installation.

From a page, the user can click a button from the editor, which then opens a modal.  In this modal I would like to have the Tags listed using the same function that one could use to select tags on a post or similar to adding it to a custom post type using 'post_tag' in the taxonomy definition.

Is it possible to access these types of functions from outside a post or page?

I am calling the modal from my TinyMCE button and am using SimpleModal.  The modal is stored in a separate PHP file.

My shortcode button and call onclick to my modal:

```
(function() {
tinymce.PluginManager.add('om_sc_button', function( editor, url ) {
    var newurl = url.substring(0, url.length -3);

    editor.addButton( 'om_sc_button', {
        title: 'Insert New Searchable Media Manager Gallery',
        image: newurl + '/images/source_code_32.png',
        onclick: function() {
                jQuery('#popup-content').load(newurl+"/includes/shortcodebuilder.php");
                jQuery('#popup-content').modal({
                    containerCss: {
                        backgroundColor: "#fff",
                        borderColor: "#000000",
                        height: 400,
                        padding: 10,
                        margin: 10,
                        width: 800
                    },
                    overlayClose: false,
                    overlayId: 'popup-overlay',
                    containerId: 'popup-container',
                    onClose: function() {
                        editor.insertContent('[MyShortcode]');
                        jQuery.modal.close();
                    }
                });
        }
    });
});
})();
```

The file shortcodebuilder.php has a form with a few input boxes and on THAT page I'd like to have the tag builder just like you see in a post.  I apologize for not posting this but the work is for a client and is proprietary. It's also why I didn't post the code earlier.

[image: WordPress Tag Builder]

Comment: Very cryptic description of code... Have you actually tried it? Please file an [edit], show us what you have tried and where you have failed.

Comment: My modal is working just fine, nothing cryptic about it. I honestly have no idea what hooks to use to use the tag library outside of a post or page.

Comment: You can look in `wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php` to see how WordPress adds those meta boxes. I doubt they'll work outside the context of an edit page though, they depend on javascript as well to work. It'll probably be easier to just build your own rather than try to make the core versions work. Your first issue of course will be that loading a php file directly will not bootstrap WordPress and you'll have no access to the API.

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding my modal via the filter `admin_footer_text` only on post/pages.  Then I built my own solution using `get_tags()` and `get_categories`.